# Value Conversion Issue: Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum NSEventMask'

Tags: objective-c, macos

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here as Xcode complains about a

```
Value Conversion Issue
   Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum NSEventMask' to different enumeration type 'NSEventModifierFlags' (aka 'enum NSEventModifierFlags')
```

It's the NSLeftMouseDownMask flag that Xcode is unhappy about.

```
NSEvent *event =  [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:NSLeftMouseDown
                                     location:menuOrigin
                                modifierFlags:(NSLeftMouseDownMask) // 0x100
                                    timestamp:0
                                 windowNumber:[[(NSButton *)sender window] windowNumber]
                                      context:[[(NSButton *)sender window] graphicsContext]
                                  eventNumber:0
                                   clickCount:1
                                     pressure:1];
```

Comment: I think you should use these constants: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000016-SW14 instead of one like `NSLeftMouseDownMask`.

Comment: That link is to a page with like 1,000 things on it, including `NSLeftMouseDownMask`, perhaps you could be a bit more specific.

Comment: Sorry, the link work for me. It should lead you to the Modifier Flags Constants (look on the left menu to find it)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Just as Larme advised, please use

```
NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask
```

replacing
    NSLeftMouseDownMask

NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask: 
Used to retrieve only the device-independent modifier flags, allowing applications to mask off the device-dependent modifier flags, including event coalescing information.